# Parse an attribute from disheveled string

Tags: php, parsing

My question is completely simple, I have a string like the following one which is quite irregular:

> package: name='com.adobe.reader' versionCode='77969'
>   versionName='10.6.1' application-label:'Adobe Reader'
>   application-label-da:'Adobe Reader' application-label-ja:'Adobe
>   Reader' application-label-de:'Adobe Reader'
>   application-label-nl:'Adobe Reader' application-label-pl:'Adobe
>   Reader' application-label-en:'Adobe Reader'
>   application-label-ko:'Adobe Reader' application-label-fr:'Adobe
>   Reader' application-label-tr:'Adobe Reader'
>   application-label-cs:'Adobe Reader' application-label-es:'Adobe
>   Reader' application-label-it:'Adobe Reader'
>   application-label-pt:'Adobe Reader' application-label-ru:'Adobe
>   Reader' application-label-sv:'Adobe Reader'
>   application-label-zh_CN:'Adobe Reader' application-label-zh_TW:'Adobe
>   Reader'
>   application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/reader_app_android.png'
>   application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/reader_app_android.png'
>   application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/reader_app_android.png'
>   application: label='Adobe Reader'
>   icon='res/drawable-mdpi/reader_app_android.png' launchable-activity:
>   name='com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader' label='' icon='' sdkVersion:'8'
>   uses-permission:'com.adobe.reader.provider.permission.READ'
>   uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
>   uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
>   uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
>   uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
>   uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
>   uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you
>   require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional' main
>   other-activities other-services supports-screens: 'small' 'normal'
>   'large' 'xlarge' supports-any-density: 'true' locales: '--_--' 'da'
>   'ja' 'de' 'nl' 'pl' 'en' 'ko' 'fr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'it' 'pt' 'ru' 'sv'
>   'zh_CN' 'zh_TW' densities: '160' '240' '320' native-code: 'armeabi'
>   'armeabi-v7a'

Is it possible to parse some value from this string (e.g the value of `versionCode`) in PHP?

Comment: Would regex like `preg_match` or `explode` be an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in PHP you could do something like this:

```
function find_var($key, $str) {
    $temp = substr($str, (strpos($str, $key)+(strlen($key)+1)));
    return substr($temp, 0, strpos($temp, "'"));
}

$val = "package: name='com.adobe.reader' versionCode='77969' versionName='10.6.1' application-label:'Adobe Reader' application-label-da:'Adobe Reader' application-label-ja:'Adobe Reader' application-label-de:'Adobe Reader' application-label-nl:'Adobe Reader' application-label-pl:'Adobe Reader' application-label-en:'Adobe Reader' application-label-ko:'Adobe Reader' application-label-fr:'Adobe Reader' application-label-tr:'Adobe Reader' application-label-cs:'Adobe Reader' application-label-es:'Adobe Reader' application-label-it:'Adobe Reader' application-label-pt:'Adobe Reader' application-label-ru:'Adobe Reader' application-label-sv:'Adobe Reader' application-label-zh_CN:'Adobe Reader' application-label-zh_TW:'Adobe Reader' application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/reader_app_android.png' application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/reader_app_android.png' application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/reader_app_android.png' application: label='Adobe Reader' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/reader_app_android.png' launchable-activity: name='com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader' label='' icon='' sdkVersion:'8' uses-permission:'com.adobe.reader.provider.permission.READ' uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET' uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE' uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen' uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional' main other-activities other-services supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge' supports-any-density: 'true' locales: '--_--' 'da' 'ja' 'de' 'nl' 'pl' 'en' 'ko' 'fr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'it' 'pt' 'ru' 'sv' 'zh_CN' 'zh_TW' densities: '160' '240' '320' native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'";
echo find_var('versionCode=', $val);
```

The above outputs: **77969**

```
echo find_var('application-label:', $val);
```

The above outputs: **Adobe Reader**

*Give it a try: [Run PHP Online](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)*

> To explain the function in pseudo:
>
> - Create a string after the position **$key** plus 1 character    *(the ' )* is found in the string passed.
> - Return a string starting from the beginning of the temporary string up to the first occurrence of the **'**

Comment: The questioner wrote: `I have a string like the following one which is quite irregular`. You may run into problems with this solution. Using regex with e.g. preg_match (see the example in my answer) allows broader matching (e.g. spaces, =, : and ' signs).

Comment: BTW: According to the amount of function calls in this solution, it's even slower than the preg_match solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match for this.

**For example:**

```
<?php
$str = '...';

function parseStr($key, $str)
{
    $regex = '/(?:'.$key.'[=:]{1})\s?\'?([^\'\s]+)\'?\s/si';
    $str   = rtrim($str).' ';

    return preg_match($regex, $str, $matches) ? $matches[1] : false;
}

var_dump(parseStr('versionCode', $str)); // Use var_dump for debugging/testing, 
                                         // put the output in a var otherwise.
```

Here's what it does:

```
Regex '/(?:'.$key.'\=)\'?([^\'\s]+)\'?\s/si':

  (?:               =>  excludes the key from the match
  '.$key.'[=:]{1})  =>  finds the key in the string
          [=:]{1}   =>  either = or : comes after the key
  \s?\'?            =>  a space or ' is optional at this point
  ([^\'\s]+)        =>  matches the desired value
  \'?\s             =>  again, ' is optional but a space is required
  /si               =>  s = single-line mode  and  i = case insensitive

rtrim($str) strips the last space (if any) of the string and .' ' adds it again.
This is done, because of the regex "\'?\s" part.

return $pr ? $match[1] : false; means, return the value or false if no match.
```

Give it a try.